# SSRS : Set bottom border line of a table row at each page end

Tags: reporting-services, border, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Problem :

I have a requirement where i need to set bottom border to the last row on each page of an SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report, Now I have a large table (tablix) that splits across several pages.
How can i do this for per page for an SSRS report?
Below is the report I have created. I would like to close tha table ieach page end.

Any help?

[image]

**Update :**
@Jesse Potter : I tried to create a line in footer and an expression in visibility.Iget the result bellow .

[image]

But how can finish the vertical line of each column

Update : screenshot of the design view of the report : 
[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the bottom border of the tablix to Black / Solid?

Comment: It does not work , i'm also try using this exression  in the bottom border of the tablix =IIF(Globals!TotalPages <> Globals!PageNumber,"Solid","None") , but i get error : i can't use global variable in the bady section

Comment: To finish the vertical line in each column, you will need to adjust your formatting so that each vertical line extends as far down as the outer lines.  Notice that the outer lines are longer than the inner lines.  You need to increase the inner lines, or shrink the outer lines.

Comment: Yes i notice that but i don't know how can i increase the inner lines

Comment: Can you post of screenshot of the design view of your report?  That might show why your lines aren't matching up as you expect.

Comment: @JessePotter The design view of the report is posted.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't tell from your layout what is causing the disconnected vertical lines.  I would recommend you turn on borders on your text boxes so that you can see where they begin and end.  You need to identify what is extending the row below the end of the vertical lines.  Basically identify what element is taking up the space you have highlighted in yellow.  Once you know what is causing this you should be able to modify that element to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If this line should appear on every page, you could add the line to the Page Footer.

In the Report menu select `Add a page footer`.  Then right click in the footer and add a line.  I was able to drag the line until it was at the very top of the report footer (it almost looked like I could move it above the report footer boundaries).  On my report this line appeared in exactly the same place as the bottom border of the last row of my table that spans multiple pages.